# $templateCache not working is state config method

Tags: angularjs

I am using gulp to add my templates into the production js file so I can access them via $templateCache. Everything works well for my directives but the templates in my state provider are not working. Its seems like the $templateCache object is not available.

Concatenated JS File. This is placed at the bottom of the file:

```
angular.module("barmehealth").run(["$templateCache",
  function($templateCache {
   $templateCache.put("app/views/register.html","<div>Register</div>");
   $templateCache.put("app/modules/framework/framework.template.html","<div class>Framework Template</div>");
  }
]);
```

I have tried both approaches below and neither work. Also there is no error. The view simply loads the index page with just gives me duplicated content.

Using templateUrl

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('barmehealth', ['framework', 'ui.router'])
    .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

      $stateProvider
      .state('register', {
        url: '/register',
        templateProvider: function($templateCache) {
          return $templateCache.get('/app/views/register.html');
        }
      });
    });
}());
```

Using templateProvider

```
    (function () {
      'use strict';

      angular.module('barmehealth', ['framework', 'ui.router'])
        .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
          $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

          $stateProvider
          .state('register', {
            url: '/register',
            templateUrl: '/app/views/register.html'
          });
        });
    }());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added extra `/` (slash) which isn't required there, by removing it you can desired template in `templateProvider` function.

Use

```
return $templateCache.get('app/views/register.html');
```

Instead of

```
return $templateCache.get('/app/views/register.html');
```